# The smallest choice of $k$ so that $\sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}$ is lower bounded by a constant

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds, distribution-tails

Let $p \in [0,1/2)$ and $\delta \in [0,1/2)$ be fixed real numbers, and let $n$ be a positive-integer valued variable.

Let $k=k(n)$ be the smallest integer for which $\delta \leq \sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}$. I would like a lower bound on $k$ in terms of $n$.

I have tried to use known [tail bounds on the binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1564088/748775), but these appear to give quite terrible bounds (if any). Indeed, the standard tail bound is given by

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} &\ge
{n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\
&= {n \choose k} \exp\left(-n(k/n \log1/p+(1-k/n)\log1/(1-p)\right)\\
&\ge \frac{\exp(n\text{H}(k/n))}{\sqrt{8k(1-k/n)}}\, \exp(-n(\text{D}(k/n||p) + H(k/n)))\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{8k(1-k/n)}}\exp(-n\text{D}(k/n||p))\\
&\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\exp(-n\text{D}(k/n||p)),
\end{align}$$
where $\text{D}(q,r)=q \log_e\left(\frac{q}{r}\right)+(1-q)\log_e\left(\frac{1-q}{1-r}\right).$ This bound decays with $n$ no matter what we choose for $k(n)$.

Comment: The CLT suggests that this bound is linear in $n$; are you basically looking for a constant of proportionality in terms of $p$ and $\delta$?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: a quick and dirty  engineering approach.

Let $q = \min(p, 1-p)$. Then

$$\sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} \ge \sum_{i=0}^k {n \choose i} q^i q^{n-i} = q^n O(n^{k+1})$$

Let the RHS converge to a non-zero constant $C$. Taking logarithms, obtain

$$n\ln{q} + (k+1)\ln{n} \approx \ln{C}$$

which means that $k = \dfrac{n}{\ln{n}}\ln{\dfrac{1}{q}}$ is a good candidate.