# The lower bound probability of Bernoulli sum is positive

Tags: probability, distribution-tails

Let $X_i$ be iid random variables.

It equals to $1$ with probability $(1+p)/2$ and equals to $-1$ with probability $(1-p)/2$.

**My question is:** What is the probability that $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i>0$?

**I tried the following deduction, but I'm very unsure about the correctness, since I plugged this result into my original problem, it seems incorrect. Could someone help to see whether I did this in the right way or if not, where could be the issue?**

Note that $\frac{X_i+1}{2}:=B_i$ is Bernoulli$(p)$ (it equals to $1$ with probability $p$). Thus $P(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i>0)=P(\sum B_i>\frac{n}{2})$. And $\sum B_i$ obeys Binomial distribution with parameter $n,p$. Moreover, $\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^nB_i)=np$.

Now I split the problem into two cases:

(1) $\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^nB_i)<\frac{n}{2}$, i.e. $p<\frac{1}{2}$ and

(2) $\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^nB_i)>\frac{n}{2}$, i.e. $p>\frac{1}{2}$

To solve the case (1).

$$P(\sum B_i>\frac{n}{2})=P\Big(\big(\sum B_i\big)-np>\frac{n}{2}-np\Big)\geq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\exp\{-nD(\frac{\frac{n+1}{2}-np}{n+1}\|p)\}$$

Here I used the estimation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130566/lower-bound-for-upper-tail-of-binomial-distribution)

To solve the case (2).

$$P(\sum B_i>\frac{n}{2})=1-P(\sum B_i<\frac{n}{2})$$

We compute the upper bound of $P(\sum B_i<\frac{n}{2})$.

$$P(\sum B_i<\frac{n}{2})=P(\sum B_i-\mathbb{E}(\sum B_i)\leq \frac{n}{2}-\mathbb{E}(\sum B_i))\leq \exp\{-np\}(\frac{enp}{t})^t$$ where $t=\frac{n}{2}-np$
where I used Chernoff’s inequality for lower tails of Bernoulli sum. See [Exercise 2.3.2](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf).

Thus $$P(\sum B_i>\frac{n}{2})=1-P(\sum B_i<\frac{n}{2})\geq 1- \exp\{-np\}(\frac{enp}{t})^t$$ where $t=\frac{n}{2}-np$

Comment: @geetha290krm the question would have an answer assuming independence

Comment: @geetha290krm I re-edited to give more information. thanks